# Hexadecimal = n times decimal

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Was explaining hexadecimal numbers to a friend and this made me wonder:

"Is there an hexadecimal number x that is a whole number n times its decimal value ?"

So for example the hexadecimal number 100 . $100_{16 }=256_{10}$ is thus 2.56 times its decimal value. (not a whole number)

But now which hexadecimal number is exactly  3 , 4  or another whole number times its decimal value?

PS: no guarantee given these numbers really exist, and have no idea what n means when it is greater than 9 (but you may think of it as hexadecimal or as decimal as you like)

Enjoy puzzling :)

Comment: computers allowed? i'm going to write  a python program...

Comment: Why not but there is nothing against the human handy work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've looked for 2 and 3 digit solutions, and couldn't find any taking n as 2-11. There are quite a few 4 digit solutions, which can be found using algebra. I found the first few at n = 4:

$4096a + 256b + 16c + d = 4 \cdot (1000a + 100b + 10c + d)$
And doing a bit of casework,
yields (in hexadecimal)

> 1038
>
> 1040
>
> 2078
>
> 2080

At this point, I am certain there are many many more, and write a python program. I set it to look for numbers less than a million, and with n less than 1000. It's still running, but here are some answers it gave, in the format $x_{16}$ (space) $n$:

1038 4
1040 4
2078 4
2080 4
2118 4
2120 4
3158 4
3160 4
3200 4
4198 4
4238 4
4240 4
5278 4
5280 4
5318 4
5320 4
6358 4
6360 4
6400 4
7398 4
7438 4
7440 4
8478 4
8480 4
8518 4
8520 4
9558 4
9560 4
9600 4
12480 6
25440 6
38400 6
112308 10
449440 10
565874 10
566080 10
678388 10
678400 10
794834 10
795040 10

I will post more as they come(EDIT: added rest of search from 1-1000000), but I feel like there are infinitely many solutions. As to proving that, I am not entirely sure how to go about it... any ideas?

For anyone with a more powerful computer than I, https://repl.it/I4vh

Answer (score 3):

To supplement thecoder16's answer, here are the results of a computer search from $1$ to $10^{10}$:

**1:** 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 9

**4:** 1038, 1040, 2078, 2080, 2118, 2120, 3158, 3160, 3200, 4198, 4238, 4240, 5278, 5280, 5318, 5320, 6358, 6360, 6400, 7398, 7438, 7440, 8478, 8480, 8518, 8520, 9558, 9560, 9600

**6:** 12480, 25440, 38400

**10:** 112308, 449440, 565874, 566080, 678388, 678400, 794834, 795040

**16:** 1123080, 4494400, 5658740, 5660800, 6783880, 6784000, 7948340, 7950400

**25:** 11702482, 24257366, 35961083, 48537120

**22:** 17996800

**35:** 187605873

**37:** 154231124

**40:** 117024820, 242573660, 359610830, 485371200

**41:** 224321889, 789458685

**42:** 846059760

**56:** 1876058730

**61:** 1365665301, 1413490122

**64:** 1170248200, 2425736600, 3596108300, 4853712000

**65:** 3502669923, 4642454565

**66:** 1067455668

**67:** 4251168226, 6375695517

**68:** 6143199678

The only pattern I can see is that if the factor n is a multiple of 5, then you can append a zero to the number to get an answer for the factor $n*8/5$.

I used this C# code:

```
for( long d=1; d<10000000000L; d++)
{
   long h = Convert.ToInt64(d.ToString(), 16);
   if (h % d == 0) Console.WriteLine(d+": "+h/d);
}
```

Comment: @oerkelens Nothing. Just a typo that has been fixed now.

Comment: ah, that's a much better algorithm then what I did :)